# Use of unresolved identifier - Swift 3

Tags: swift3, grand-central-dispatch, func

I have a problem with the following code in Swift3. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but when I try to print 'list' I receive a compiler error 'Use of unresolved identifier'. Can anybody point me the right direction?

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

DispatchQueue.main.async {

    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode == 200 {

        do {

        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:   JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]

        guard let list = json?["response"] as? [[String : Any]] else {
                            return
                        }
        } catch {
            print("catch error...")
          }

     } //end of if let httpStatus

}//end dispacth

}//end of task

task.resume()

print(list)
```

Comment: `list` is out of scope (the async block). Aside from that `list` would be empty at that moment anyway.

Comment: Try printing list just before the `} catch {` and see what you get.

Comment: @PhillipMills If I print list before } catch, then I get a proper result. However, how can I work with the data form the List outside of the do/catch clause? List includes data that will need to populate TableView. I am not sure how I can get data from List into the table rows?

Comment: You don't work with `list` outside the `do` block. You assign `list` to an appropriate property in your class and then reload your table view. BTW - why are you doing the JSON parsing on the main thread? Only reload the table on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised your code even compiles since `list` is not in the same scope as your `print` command. The compiler should be catching that.

Essentially, the problem is that `list` is defined inside the `do` block. This means that the scope of `list` is limited to only the `do` block. Like @vadian said in his comment, execute `print(list)` after your `guard` statement and before the line containing `} catch {`. `list` will be in scope there and have the value of `json?["response"] as? [[String : Any]]` as long as that value is not `nil` (in which case the `guard` block will execute and return from the `Dispatch.main.async` block).

New code:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

DispatchQueue.main.async {

    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode == 200 {

        do {

        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:   JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]

        guard let list = json?["response"] as? [[String : Any]] else {
            print("list variable is nil")
            return
        }

        print(list)

        } catch {
            print("catch error...")
        }

     } //end of if let httpStatus

}//end dispacth

}//end of task

task.resume()
```

Also, note that since you're not doing any UI updates (at least yet) here, you do not need to execute this code on the main thread. You could use this instead:

```
DispatchQueue.global(attributes: .qosDefault).async {

}
```